# How to use files in another Project in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I have a solution with two project in Visual Studio 2005. I want to use Project2's files in Project1. I included the head file and compiled it successfully. There comes the error LNK2019 when linking. However it runs well in project2 using the same file.

It is not about the obj path, cause I have tried move them to the same folder.
I have searched a lot on msdn if Build Event can help. But I have no answer.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e85wte0k(v=vs.80).aspx

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Project2 is a library, then all you have to do is link Project1 against Project2 by right-clicking Project1 -> Project dependencies and select Project2. If Project2 is not a library, then you must include the sources to Project1 as well, that is by clicking Project1->Add existing Items, and selecting the relevant cpp files from Project2. Hth

Comment: Thx, your second method saved my life. How can it works? Why add an obj file cannot run?

Comment: @Nickolas: What do you mean? The header file alone isn't enough. The source must be linked either via a lib, or explicitly be put to your project so that it gets compiled when the project compiles

Comment: I thought the source will be compiled in the solution. Tt runs well now ,Thx Armen.

Comment: @Nickolas: No, a solution is just a way to organize projects, set dependencies between them, specify build order etc. And you're most welcome ;)